# What is the correct way to manage fragments backstack and onBackButton on android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to know how to properly use backstack on fragments for getting to the previous fragment. 
  Im using this in every new fragment replace i need to do:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, myFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

It works but when i do:

```
 Main frag > A frag > B frag
```

and press back two times to return to Main Frag and do it again:

```
 Main frag > A frag > B frag
```

it first return to the first B then first A and then Main frag (i know because my fragments load db data).

**EDIT** 
  Its a product management system, so first B is the fragment B loaded with product 1 data, and when i go to list fragment (A frag) and click product 2 and hit back, it returns to the first product loaded (fragment B loaded with item 1 data) instead of returning to the list fragment (A frag).

So i want to know what is the correct way to manage the `onBackPress` and BackStack on fragments?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this: "it first return to the first B them first A and them Main frag"

Comment: You shouldn't have to manage `onBackPressed` manually. Are you overriding `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: No, just calling it on an action bar onClickItem listener. Can you please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021131/manage-backstack-on-android-fragments-for-add-and-edit-data) , it explain better what im trying to do and the nature of the problem. Thank you again.